# Prevent Symfony from displaying overriden error templates for a given bundle

Tags: rest, symfony, twig

We're currently developing a REST API (well, kind of) as a separate bundle inside an already existing Symfony project. The main bundle in this project is a backoffice application.

We have HTML error templates which override the default ones. But we want these templates to be rendered *only* when the error occurs within the backoffice bundle. For the REST bundle, we want the error message to be displayed as plain text.

Is there a not-too-hacky way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

The error templates are picked up by the default ExceptionController provided by the TwigBundle. You can register your own exception controller and check if the error occured in the backoffice, if so it'll use the custom template locations and otherwise it'll fallback to the TwigBundle templates.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/error_pages.html#replace-the-default-exception-controller for more information